# How can I see the difference between commits and current state, not commit?

Tags: git

My question is just same as the title.

I learned how to see the difference between commits, but I don't know how when I want to see between the last commit and current state, not the commit!

Aren't there no direct ways to do this?

Comment: Use `git help diff` into your terminal or read the same manual page on the web: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `git diff` with no commit will show the difference between the index and the working tree. If you haven't `git add`ed or `git rm`ed anything, then the index will be the same as the last commit.

`git diff --cached` will show the difference between the last commit and the index.

`git diff HEAD` will show the difference of the working tree from the last commit (`HEAD`). This will be the combination of the changes in the index and the change between the index and the working tree.

Comment: Note also that `git diff --cached` implies `git diff --cached HEAD`. You can compare *any* existing commit to the index this way: `git diff <commit>` means *compare named commit to work-tree* and `git diff --cached <commit>` means *compare named commit to index*. The odd man out here is `git diff` with no arguments, which means *compare index to work-tree* – most non-diff Git commands, with no additional commit-name specified, have an implied `HEAD`, but with `git diff`, the implied `HEAD` only occurs when you add `--cached`.